# how to convert json to vars in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash, youtube-api

Hello i'm  trying to use the youtube api in rails, i'm newbie in ruby. I parse a Jason and i save it into a hash. But i don't now how to access to the keys and print in the views.

```
@response = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLUoqTnNH-2Xz_BUrjcahKWDhPcUj-FTOt?v=2&alt=json').body)
```

I have tried first to print in a view  `<%= @response[:title][:$t] %>` i get nil

I want to do the same as the javascript above, that shows a list of vids of a youtube playlist.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    var playList= "PLUoqTnNH-2Xz_BUrjcahKWDhPcUj-FTOt";
    var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+ playList +'?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    $.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
    var list_data="";
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
        list_data += '<li><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"</a><p> Title "'+ feedTitle +'" </li>';
    });
    $(list_data).appendTo(".cont");
  });
 </script>

 <ul class="cont">
</ul>

</html>
```

Can anybody give me a clue or a tutorial to follow to do this in rails ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your question, you want to print out the title? if you want to do so try:

```
@response["feed"]["title"]["$t"]
```

If you want to get the feed list you can do something like:

```
@response["feed"]["entry"].each do |entry|
  puts entry.inspect 
end
```

I highly recommend you to build a wrapper class to handle the methods instead of getting the results directly.

Comment: Thank this is exactly what i'm asking for.